# react final form validation outside of form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I want to check whether form fields are valid from outside the form as my form is a modal and closes on button press. The button is not part of form. My modal(form) should not close when there are validation errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a code sample of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try validation the form inside the component first and when the form is valid you have to send it to the receiving component for further processsing.
`if (formValid) this.processTheForm( formdata );`